# Rails simulate application instance / request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am following along with the following:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

I'm trying to test the middleware using rspec.

I'm not sure the best approach to this.

I am trying to get at the request headers to see if the request is from a mobile device.

It seems like I would somehow need to pass in an application instance, but would also need to simulate request headers?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test middleware with Rspec you need to define a method that makes an instance of your middleware either by doing

```
let(:inner_app) { lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['All good!'] } }


let(:app) { SomeMiddleware.new }
```

or

```
def app
  SomeMiddleware.new
end
```

You'll also have to include the module `Rack::Test::Methods` in either your `spec_helper.rb` or your test file.

Then any request you do in Rspec will go through that middleware.

Check this resource out http://blog.kesor.net/2012/06/05/rack-middleware/